# Background Image repeating when resizing windows width

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a page that has a background image in between a `header` and `footer` will work on any screen size.

I have managed to create the page and it works fine on desktop screen. The problem i have is when I resize to `mobile size screen` then the background is repeated.

Here is my code:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5886px;
    background-image: url('services-yellow.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Has the height attribute set at a specific height, but i am not sure how i can change this so that it works on all screen sizes.

The site can be viewed at: http://s116169771.websitehome.co.uk/testsite/

If somebody could please advise on how i could fix this, would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`none` is not a valid value for `background-repeat`, use `no-repeat` instead.

background-repeat property ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)) ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp))

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) of possible values for background-repeat, you need:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

None doesn't exist for this property.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-repeat:no-repeat`

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5886px;
    background-image: url('services-yellow.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
}
```

or simply short the code

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5886px;
    background: url('services-yellow.jpg') no-repeat 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `background-repeat: none;` to `background-repeat: no-repeat;` `none` is not a valid value for `background-repeat` property.

Your code should be:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5886px;
  background-image: url('services-yellow.jpg');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
}
```

You can also use short hand css `background` property as follows:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5886px;
  background: url('services-yellow.jpg') no-repeat 100% auto;
  border: none;
}
```

[More Details](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate it for all your answers. Btw is there anyway to reduce the height, as now I have a big white space at the bottom. Would I need to add a media query to control this? or is there a way to do it within the same code?

Comment: @user3191160 Better use `img` in `HTML`. Place your image inside `div` and style it like `div img {display: block; height: auto; width: 100%;` and remove `height` from your `div`.

Comment: Thank u Muhammad, that works, but im guessing this wouldnt work if i was to add text on top of the image as this would no longer on top of the image..

Comment: @user3191160 You can place image or text with `position: absolute` as more suits your need with `z-index` if needed.